# API - URI Advice

Tags: api-design

Our API will return a list of products and depending on the page is querying these products the required parameters and internal logic varies, in total, we have 4 different pages

so we have in our minds two options for the URI construction

- option 1:

`v1/products/search-page?searchTearm=test&searchRequiredField1=xxx&..`

`v1/products/category-page?productId-123&&productRequiredField1=xxx&..`

- option 2:

`v1/products-search-page?searchTearm=test&searchRequiredField1=xxx&..`

`v1/products-category-page?categoryId=123&&categoryRequiredField1=xxx&..`

I'm not quite sure which one makes more sense I found some pro/con in both

Comment: You could have `/products` be the search page, and `/products/24601` be the page for product 24601?

Comment: no, all options will return a list of products, not looking to show only one or specific product